# Beth number - justify existence of Beth omega

Tags: set-theory

I read through the answers to previous questions regarding Beth numbers and  was unable to find the answer to my question, so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

I am studying the definition of Beth numbers, specifically:

$\beth_0:=\aleph_0$

$\beth_{\alpha+1}:=2^{\beth_\alpha}$

$\beth_\lambda:=\displaystyle\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}\beth_\alpha$ for limit ordinals $\lambda$

How is the third line of the definition justified? How do we know that the power set operation can be applied an infinite number of times? Is there a way to show rigorously that $\beth_\omega$ for example, exists? Would I need a version of the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: This is a definition by recursion; you need the recursion theorem, which does not use Choice.

Comment: The supremum of any set of cardinals/ordinals exists.  Recursion gives you that each of the $\beth_n$ exist, so their supremum $\beth_\omega$ exists.  For larger limit ordinals, you would use Transfinite Induction or Recursion.

Comment: You do need AC (Axiom of Choice) to show that $\beth (x)$ is always a (cardinal )  ordinal.  Without AC you cannot even show that $\mathbb R$ can be well-ordered.

Comment: @user254665 It depends exactly what you mean by "$\beth(x)$". There is a natural choiceless definition: the supremum of the cardinals onto which $\mathcal{P}(x)$ surjects. This definition requires no choice to analyze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment, recall the following version of the Recursion Theorem reads, where $\phi$ is a formula in the language of set theory:

> Suppose that $\forall x \exists! y\phi(s,y)$, and define $G(s)$ to be the unique $y$ such that $\phi(s,y)$ (note the use Replacement). Then we can define a formula $\psi$ for which the following are provable.
>
> 1. $\forall x \exists! y \psi(x,y)$, so $\psi$ defines a functions $F$, where $F(x)$ is the $y$ such that $\psi(x,y)$.
> 2. $\forall\xi\in ON [F(\xi)=G(F\upharpoonright\xi)]$.

where $F\upharpoonright\xi$ means $F$ restricted to $\xi$. For a proof and some comments on the statement of the theorem, see Kunen's *Foundations of Mathematics*, page 45.

To apply this theorem, we need only specify $G$. We let:

$$
G(s)=
\begin{cases}
\aleph_0 & \text{if $s=0$}\\
2^{s(\eta)} & \text{if $s$ is a function with dom$(s)=\eta+1$ a successor ordinal}\\
\sup_{\alpha<\lambda} s(\alpha) & \text{if $s$ is a function with dom$(s)=\lambda$ a limit ordinal}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

You can now apply (2) in the theorem to this $G$ to see that $F$ is the desired $\beth$ function.

Comment: +1. Note that we can sidestep the Recursion Theorem in the specific case the OP asks about: it is is a direct consequence of Replacement. There is a formula $\varphi(x, y)$ in the language of set theory such that for all $n\in\omega$, we have $\varphi(n, a)\iff a=\beth_n$; by Replacement, the range of this function exists, and the union of the range is exactly $\beth_\omega$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber that's actually pretty neat, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @NoahSchweber using that same logic could I build upon $\beth_\omega$ by applying Replacement again (similar to the construction of the ordinal numbers)? Example: $\forall n\in\omega$, we have $\phi_(n,a) \Leftrightarrow a=\beth_{\omega +n}$, which gives me $\beth_{\omega+\omega}$... and so on and so on. So long as I only use cardinals I've previously constructed?